# Dart math calculations are inaccurate

Tags: dart

Dart calculations are off. We're running into rounding issues (financial app)

Here an [example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=76bf6e10579ca3b9c19ca2b454164521)

Dartpad output

```dart
Hours              : 7.5
Rate               : 19.61
Val (Hours * Rate) : 147.075

Val * 100 (should be 14707.5) : 14707.499999999998
Round Val (now rounds down)   : 14707
Val / 100                     : 147.07 (should have been 147.08)
```

This is causing rounding errors displaying values to 2 decimal places.

Is there a way to accomplish this accurately in dart?

Comment: Regarding what to do in Dart: if you care about *decimal* precision, then you can use [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a floating point precision thing, nothing really to do with the language itself. There are many ways around this problem. See mine below.

```
void main() {
  var vHours = 7.5;
  print('Hours              : $vHours');
  
  var vRate = 19.61;
  print('Rate               : $vRate');

  var vValue = vHours * vRate;
  print('Val (Hours * Rate) : $vValue');

  print('');
  var vMul = (vValue * 100);
  var vMulString = vMul.toStringAsFixed(2);
  var vMulParsed = num.parse(vMulString);
  print('Val * 100 (should be 14707.5) : $vMulParsed');
  var vMulRounded = vMulParsed.round();
  print('Round Val (now rounds down)   : $vMulRounded');
  
  var vDiv = vMulRounded / 100;
  print('Val / 100                     : $vDiv (should have been 147.08)');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this will work for what we need.